# socket programming c++ and python: client server chat communication breaks after client sents the second message to the server. Why?

Tags: python, c++, sockets, chat

The server is running code in python. The client is running code in C++. The server starts connection to the server which is working fine,it accepts the user input and sends the first message to the server(this is happening inside the while loop). The server dispays the client message and takes input from the user on the server and sends it to the client. The client displays the server message. It takes input from the user and attemps to send it to the server but the server is not showing anytning. It looks like it is still waiting for the response from the client. No errors are displayed. I am new to socketing programming and I have researched similar implementations that promise to work but so far it is not working. If i remove the while loop from the client it works as intended. the message is sent to the server and the client program termninates but the purpose of the chat is to be continious communication till one of the parties doens't close the connection which is handled by conditionals. Any help would be appreciated!

Server side loop in python:

```
while 1:
    connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()
    sentence = connectionSocket.recv(4096)
    print sentence
    serverSentence = raw_input('Me >: ')
    denial = 'The Connection was ended by the server.Bye!'
    if serverSentence == '\quit':
        connectionSocket.send(denial)
        connectionSocket.close()
    else:
        fullResponse = 'Server > ' + serverSentence
        connectionSocket.send(fullResponse)
```

client side loop in C++:

```
while(1)
    {
        cout << "Me >";
        string data;
        getline(cin, data);
        name.append(data);  

        memset(&msg, 0, sizeof(msg));//clear the buffer
        strcpy(msg, name.c_str());
        if(data == "\\quit")
        {\
            send(clientSd, (char*)&msg, strlen(msg), 0);
            break;
        }
        bytesWritten += send(clientSd, (char*)&msg, strlen(msg), 0);

        memset(&msg, 0, sizeof(msg));//clear the buffer
        bytesRead += recv(clientSd, (char*)&msg, sizeof(msg), 0);
        /*if(strcmp(msg, "quit"))
        {
            cout << "Server has quit the session" << endl;
            break;
        }*/
        cout<< msg << endl;
    }

    close(clientSd);
    cout << "The client has closed the connection. Bye!" << endl;
```

Comment: Your Python code's loop looks like each iteration, it accepts a brand new connection, reads a message and displays it; it does not have a loop just reading from the already established socket. This contrasts with what your C++ code is trying to do.

Comment: Phil M, I see what you mean. It totally makes sense! I took the first line of the while loop in server code out of the loop and it works perfectly well now! I ve been trying to modify the client code a lot but eventually i ve figured that the error should be somewhere on the server. It took me hours to do it. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: The only thing that is happening now is that when I type "\quit" in the server it would give me an error of "Bad file descriptor" and terminate the program.

Comment: Unrelated, but you should be checking the return value of send/recv. They should return -1 on error.